# AJAX, Laravel 4.2 - POST status cancelled, how to post to route

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http, laravel

I have been racking my brain about this one for a while. I have a block of Jquery that sends a AJAX post to a url within the website. This logic happens when the user redirects away from the current page that they are on.

The problem is that I am on the url with the Jquery script, I redirect away from the page and then check the developer console in chrome and comes up with a POST with a status of cancelled. And I check the table in my database and it hasnt inserted the record, so I take it that the status meant it could never reach the URL.

The route file with the ajaxtest route defined

```
<?php
 Route::post('ajaxtest', array('before' => 'adminFilter', 'uses' =>    'TestsController@ajaxTest'));
?>
```

The method in the Controller involved

```
  <?php
   public function ajaxTest() {
   DB::table('test_ajax')->insert(
            array('test_string' => 'TestTest')
        );
   if (Request::isJson())  {
        $name = Input::get('name');
        $age = Input::get('age');
        DB::table('test_ajax')->insert(
            array('test_string' => $name.'|'.$age)
        );
    } else {
        DB::table('test_ajax')->insert(
            array('test_string' => $name.'|'.$age)
        );
    }
}
?>
```

The Jquery involved that is meant to make a AJAX post to ajaxtest url if the user redirects away from the current page.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     console.log("Host url" + window.location.host);
     var formFlag = false;

    $("#submitTest").click(function() {
     formFlag = true;
    });
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    if(!formFlag){
        return "Your changes may not be saved.";
    }
}
$( window ).unload(function() {
    $.post("<?php echo Request::root(); ?>/ajaxtest/", { name: "John", age: "26" });
});
</script>
```

The request information on the developer console, with status of cancelled.

```
Request URL:http://192.168.0.9/ajaxtest/
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:*/*
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://192.168.0.9
Referer:http://192.168.0.9/tests/question
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
name:John
age:26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$.post` is asynchronous method, `$( window ).unload(..)` does not wait to perform it and cancels it. Try to change this

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
    $.post("<?php echo Request::root(); ?>/ajaxtest/", { name: "John", age: "26" });
});
```

To this:

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo Request::root(); ?>/ajaxtest/',
        data: { name: "John", age: "26" },
        async: false
    });
});
```

It calls POST like synchronous method so browser should wait until it ends up and then unloads.
But this is not recommendet to wait for somethin in `unload`. It may not be user friendly.

Comment: Well it kind of works, I have now got a 405 status (Method not allowed) despite the fact that on the route I have specified it as POST, Really confused about that one.

Comment: @MatthewUnderwood Are you unloading to same domain? e.g. you are at `http://sth.com/...`. Do you stay on the same domain `http://sth.com/...` or move to another `http://newsth.com/...` after unload?

Comment: I am unloading to the same domain.